# any hash table in C besides from search.h?

Tags: c, hash

I'm searching hash table implementations in C, but the only one I could find was from `search.h`. It would be perfect if it allowed me to make more tables. Does someone know a hash implementation, like the one from `search.h` (where I can create tables, put any struct on it and search based on a key), but that also allowed me to create more than one table at the same time?

Comment: Have you considered writing your own?

Comment: I've used uthash(http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/) in my projects and it's worked fine.